# WCF stopped responding after 25 calls

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I got a WCF service which stopped responding after several calls...

I ran a test and I found out after 25 calls I need to reset iis/vs iis..

On the client side each function starts with

```
ServiceClient vs = new ServiceClient();
```

and finishes with

```
vs.Close();
```

so I'm guessing each call is a connection?

Where and how do I need to configure WCF to accept a larger number of connections?

Thanks.

p.s i'm using .net 4.0

Answer (score 3):

Your WCF service will have a maximum number of concurrent callers - 25 might be the default.

This is set to a low default values - by design, so a malicious caller cannot just simply bring down your server.

There is a service behavior called `ServiceThrottling` which you can specify on your server side that allows you to define higher values - see the [relevant MSDN documentation for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735114%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Basically, on your server side, you need to define this behavior:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior  name="Throttled">
      <serviceThrottling 
        maxConcurrentCalls="100" 
        maxConcurrentSessions="100" 
        maxConcurrentInstances="100" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

and then make sure your service references that behavior:

```
<service name="YourServiceName" behaviorConfiguration="Throttled"> 
   ....
</service>
```